# reindex on a multi index changes structure and drops index names

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, scipy

I am attempting to to a reindex of a multi index Pandas.Series using a list of tuples. The structure of the Series is as follows

```
(Pdb) object

respondent  brand    
0           Asda     6
1           Tesco    7
2           Asda     9
3           Aldi     2
4           Asda     4
Name: rating, dtype: int64
```

and the multi index structure is as follows

```
(Pdb) obj.index
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [u'Aldi', u'Asda', u'Tesco']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'respondent', u'brand'])
```

After I do the reindex as follows

```
indexes = [(0, u'Asda'), (0, u'Tesco'), (0, u'Aldi'), (0, u'pick'), (1, u'Asda'), (1, u'Tesco'), (1, u'Aldi'), (1, u'pick'), (2, u'Asda'), (2, u'Tesco'), (2, u'Aldi'), (2, u'pick'), (3, u'Asda'), (3, u'Tesco'), (3, u'Aldi'), (3, u'pick'), (4, u'Asda'), (4, u'Tesco'), (4, u'Aldi'), (4, u'pick')]

obj.reindex(index=indexes, fill_value=default)
```

The result is

```
0  Asda     6
   Tesco    0
   Aldi     0
   pick     0
1  Asda     0
   Tesco    7
   Aldi     0
   pick     0
2  Asda     9
   Tesco    0
   Aldi     0
   pick     0
3  Asda     0
   Tesco    0
   Aldi     2
   pick     0
4  Asda     4
   Tesco    0
   Aldi     0
   pick     0
```

and the multi index is now

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [u'Aldi', u'Asda', u'Tesco', u'pick']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3]])
```

This is a problem as the index names have been dropped. Is there any way to prevent this ? How can it be fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we can make a new `DataFrame` and add the values to the new one from the original `DataFrame`:

```
In [134]:

print df
                  v
respondent brand   
0          Asda   6
1          Tesco  7
2          Asda   9
3          Aldi   2
4          Asda   4
In [135]:

Index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((df.index.get_level_values(0).unique(), 
                                    df.index.get_level_values(1).unique()),
                                   names = df.index.names)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'v': np.zeros(len(Index))},
                   index = Index)
In [136]:

print (df2+df).fillna(0)
                  v
respondent brand   
0          Aldi   0
           Asda   6
           Tesco  0
1          Aldi   0
           Asda   0
           Tesco  7
2          Aldi   0
           Asda   9
           Tesco  0
3          Aldi   2
           Asda   0
           Tesco  0
4          Aldi   0
           Asda   4
           Tesco  0
```

Comment: thats actually a really good answer ! The only problem is that I cant assume that missing column values will always be filled with 0. I didn't mention this above though.

Comment: skip the `.fillna(0)` part will level the empty cells `nan`.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a slightly different approach which worked out better for me. I ended up building an new Index/MultiIndex, naming it correctly and then doing the reindex on this.

```
def re_index(obj, default, indexes):
    if isinstance(indexes[0], list):
        complete_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(indexes)
        complete_index.names = obj.index.names
    else:
        complete_index = pd.Index(data=indexes, name=obj.index.name)
        complete_index.name = obj.index.name

    new_obj = copy.copy(obj)
    return new_obj.reindex(index=complete_index, fill_value=default)
```